# Plotting two functions with dependent input function

Tags: plotting, functions, color

I have defined a function:

```
myJ2[n_] := 1/n* Total[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]^2]
```

This is basically an approximation to the gaussian integral. I want to plot this and the error graph (difference between the approximation and the exact value) at the same time. Using a random variable makes this difficult. I tried this:

```
DiscretePlot[{myJ2[n], 1 - myJ2[n]}, {n, 1, 1000}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]
```

However, this is not quite correct, since the myJ2 function is called twice and hence gives different values due to the randomness. I improved this by using:

```
DiscretePlot[{x, 1 - x} /. x -> myJ2[n], {n, 1, 1000}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

This gives me the correct values but both in the same color. How can I get both the function and the error function displayed in two graphs or with two different colors?

Thanks

Charly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I noted in an [answer to another recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11622/8), there are several different ways to generate a list that depends on an iterator index, including `Table` and `Array`. In this particular case, I think `Array` is more succinct. (On my machine, there seems to be a very slight speed advantage over `Table`, as well, but it is too small to care about for this particular problem.

```
data = Array[myJ2, {1000}];
```

It is worth knowing that [arithmetic operations are `Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html), so you can just write `1-data` to get the second series. This is almost always the fastest (and most succinct code) to get things done, as it avoids all the loop, iterator and `Map` paraphernalia.

You also don't need to transpose anything. Notice I have used `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot`, which removes the need to specify the `Joined` option.

```
ListLinePlot[{data, 1 - data}]
```

[image: plot of data]

Comment: I somehow missed this post.  I came here because someone downvoted my answer; now I guess I know why.

Comment: I didn't suppose that it was.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I did not had the idea to put the results in a resultset before. Anyway, this looks exactly what I was looking for. I tried Table and Array for some more than just 1000 calcs, but the timing is always nearly the same. I'd go for Array, since it's shorter ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to call your function twice :

```
data = Table[myJ2[n], {n, 1, 1000}];

ListPlot[{Transpose[{Range[1000], data}], Transpose[{Range[1000], 1 - data}]}, 
    Filling -> None,  Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: More succinct `data = Table[myJ2[n], {n, 1, 1000}]; ListPlot[{data, 1 - data}, 
 Joined -> True]`

Comment: Or `ListPlot[Transpose[{#, 1 - #} & /@ Array[myJ2, {1000}]], 
 Joined -> True]`

Comment: This one is also nice, but I'd go for the first example, since it is shorter and easier to read. Thanks anyway!